# How to set size of Image.Source which is a static resource in XAML?

Tags: wpf, image

I have the following `Image` in my GUI:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5" Source="{Binding SelectedExternalCameraDevice.LiveStreamSource, FallbackValue={StaticResource LivestreamDefaultImage}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource LivestreamDefaultImage}}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

The static resource for the fallback and targetnullvalue look as follows (This is basically taken from [Windows's Image library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) - it is the icon "PlayVideo"):

```
    <DrawingImage x:Key="LivestreamDefaultImage" >
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{ui:DynamicColor SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}" Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{ui:DynamicColor SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" Geometry="F1M16,4L16,12C16,13.103,15.103,14,14,14L2,14C0.897,14,0,13.103,0,12L0,4C0,2.897,0.897,2,2,2L14,2C15.103,2,16,2.897,16,4" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{ui:DynamicColor SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}" Geometry="F1M6,11L6,5 10.954,8z M14,3L2,3C1.448,3,1,3.448,1,4L1,12C1,12.552,1.448,13,2,13L14,13C14.552,13,15,12.552,15,12L15,4C15,3.448,14.552,3,14,3" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{ui:DynamicColor SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" Geometry="F1M6,5L10.954,8 6,11z" />
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

As soon as the bound ImageSource in the ViewModel has a proper image, the `Image` control will stretch uniformly to the available space, keeping it's aspect ration. However, while the source is null the image takes the static resource as source, I have some default aspect ratio (which looks like 1:1). How can I set the width/height/aspect ration of the `LivestreamDefaultImage`, so that it will also stretch to the available space with my chosen dimensions?

Comment: The aspect ratio of the DrawingImage is determined by the bounding box of its Drawing. In order to stretch it non-uniformly, set `Stretch="Fill"`.

Comment: @Clemens sorry, for the confusion: I want the Image control to stretch uniformly (which I need in case the source is not null). However I would like to change the "dimensions" of the fallback DrawingImage. Basically what I need for the Image would be  `Stretch="Fill"` in case the `Image.Source` is null and `Stretch="Uniform"` otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then try this Style:

```
    <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding SelectedExternalCameraDevice.LiveStreamSource}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedExternalCameraDevice.LiveStreamSource}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource LivestreamDefaultImage}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer, I'll test it out tomorrow - not in the office anymore

Comment: Perhaps I confused where "Fill" is needed, and where "Uniform" is.
But you yourself are able to correct this.